# Looking for papers/research on linking/compile time optimizations for report

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker

I was wondering whether anyone had any good resources (papers/articles/book references) on compile/linking optimizations.

I had worked in two companies that performed their linking operations differently.

1. The First Company forced a strict DAG structure for the code explaining to me that with a forced tree structure that linking times are crazy fast
2. The second company employed "master cpps" where they had few cpps that actually included all other ones. (the other ones were then excluded to be compiled from the project).

Both have their advantages/disadvantages and I was hoping on writing a paper for my school report on this subject and just looking for material.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not exactly recent, but [this site](http://gamesfromwithin.com/physical-structure-and-c-part-1-a-first-look) has a series of interesting articles regarding physical structure and compilation time. You may also want to know that what you encountered in the second company is often referred to as the [Single Compilation Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) technique.

Comment: thanks. Didn't know the name. I wonder if the DAG method has a 'name' as well.

Comment: In Lakos book, it's called "levelization."

Answer (score 1):

[Large Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) is a good reference for this kind of stuff.